# Android bitmap get pixels

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap

Ok so I already know this question has been asked but I didn't get a satisfactory answer. I don't understand the integer that is returned by getPixel() of Bitmap in android. When I tried it, it gave me some long negative integer that I had no idea about what it was representing. I know that it returns a "Color" but what does that mean? What does that long number mean?

Comment: What part of http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html do you not understand.

Comment: It just says stuff about argb not some negative long number that doesn't make any sense..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about the value itself. All you need to know is that it bundles together four numbers about the pixel colour - the amount of red, the amount of green, the amount of blue and the alpha value. All 4 numbers are between 0 and 255. An alpha value of 0 means totally transparent and 255 means not transparent at all. You can get these 4 numbers out of the int by calling Color.getRed() etc

Comment: OK thanks that's what I needed go know! Btw just out of curiosity why is the number negative?

Comment: There's nothing surprising about it - 50% of ints are negative. It's too complicated to explain in a comment. You need to look up two's complement representations of numbers.